# android covertion of HexaDecimal color to octal

Tags: android, colors

I want to give color programatically to a Button, like

```
button.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

For that i want to give some color like `#312D27` in hexadecimal format.
But its not supporting if i ll give like bellow,

```
 button.setBackgroundColor(#312D27);
```

for that I have to give like,

```
 button.setBackgroundColor(0x312D27);
```

but I am not getting the same color as in hexadecimal format.
How can I get in octal format?

Comment: you can also give `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);` or `button.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);`

Comment: I know that. But I dont want that color. I want different color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happen, **To use hexadecimal format you have to parse that hex code into color so `Color.Parse()` will do it for you..**

```
 button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#312D27"));
```